# getting null value in enddate parameter after passing setDate value to controller action method's enddate parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Javascript code

```
function setDate(id) {

        debugger;
        $('#doctorId').val(id.name);
        $('#hhduration').val(id.id);
        var datesArray = [];
        var d = new Date();
        var startdate = d.toLocaleString();
        var ed = new Date();
        ed.setDate(d.getDate() + 12);
        var Enddate = ed.toLocaleString();
        var doctorId = id.name;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAvailabledates", "Home")',
            data: { startdate: startdate, enddate: Enddate, doctorid: doctorId },
            datatype: "json",
            async: false
        }).done(function (data) {

            try {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    debugger;
                    datesArray = data;
                }



            }
            catch (e) {

            }
        });
```

MVC Controller method

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetAvailabledates(DateTime startdate,DateTime? enddate,string doctorid)
        {
            int[] dates = null;
            using (DepartmentOperations dos = new DepartmentOperations())
            {
                 dates = dos.GetAvailabledates(startdate, enddate, doctorid);
            }
            return Json(dates, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Use browser Developer Console (Network tab) to inspect values sent by browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Json Signify make Enddate not null if you do not pass date then it will pass as '0001-01-01 00:00:00'

one more thing if you want to set nullable thing then it should be last in parameter of the controller

https://cmatskas.com/asp-net-mvc-webapi-optional-parameters/

Comment: No, actually the problem is am passing startdate and enddate both to the controller but am getting only startdate in controller and enddate is coming null but why?

Comment: As I told you nullable must be at last parameter (string doctorid) is not nullable: It Should be like this (startdate,doctorid,enddate)

Comment: I tried that also than also its getting null only in enddate, and getting doctorid and startdate. only enddate am not able to get, one more thing is while passing am adding 12 days to current date for enddate right, if i pass current date like how am passing to startdate than am getting value in enddate parameter in controller.

Comment: Try with passing { startdate: startdate, enddate: ed.toLocaleString(), doctorid: doctorId }

Comment: I got it, actually is my system date format is day/month/year but controller expecting month/day/year. Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: if you do not use d.toLocaleString() then also it works fine

Answer (score 0):

If you're experiencing issues with the current approach and would like to try a different method for passing the enddate parameter, you could consider using a JSON payload in your POST request. Here's an example of how you can modify your controller action method and the way you send data to it:

```
public ActionResult GetAvailabledates([FromBody] DateInputModel dateInput)
{
    int[] dates = null;
    using (DepartmentOperations dos = new DepartmentOperations())
    {
        dates = dos.GetAvailabledates(dateInput.StartDate, dateInput.EndDate, dateInput.DoctorId);
    }
    return Json(dates, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public class DateInputModel
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public string DoctorId { get; set; }
}
```